# Magnetic Field due to finite wire

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

While deriving formula for magnetic field due to a finite current carrying wire, we have used **Biot -Savart law**, but here in this wire there is accumulation of charge at ends and thus it is non-static situation, and **Biot-Savart law** is only vaild for static situation.

[image]

But the formula derieved by it is correct, why ?

Comment: The accumulation of charge isn't considered here. It's a field due to a current wire segment in which a constant steady current is flowing.

Comment: @YoungKindaichi But dosen't accumulation of charge also create an additional field ?

Comment: The charges that accumulate at the end points of the wire generate an electric field but no magnetic field. That's why they do not appear in Biot-Savart formula. However, when applying Ampere theorem, these charges contribute to the displacement current.